# Reverse sorting Shell sort in Python

Tags: python-2.7, sorting

I want to sort a list using Shell sort, but in the reverse mode.
What do I need to change in my code to make the sorting descending?
This is my working code:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import resource
start = timer()
def shellSort(array):
     gap = len(array) // 2
     # loop over the gaps
     while gap > 0:
         # do the insertion sort
         for i in range(gap, len(array)):
             val = array[i]
             j = i
             while j >= gap and array[j - gap] > val:
                 array[j] = array[j - gap]
                 j -= gap
             array[j] = val
         gap //= 2
with open('lista.txt', 'r') as f:
    long_string = f.readline()
    alist = long_string.split(',')
shellSort(alist)
f = open("shell.txt", "w")
print >>f,(alist)
print resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / 1000
end = timer()
print(end - start)
f.close()
print 'Shell\n'
```

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array[j-gap] < gap`

Or just reverse the final list using `reversed()` method like:
`reversed(array)`